# why broken image is inserting in longblob

Tags: image, phpmyadmin, byte

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    $StyleName = $_POST['StyleName'];
    $Description = $_POST['Desc'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO viewcutlist (CutName,Description,Image)
        VALUES ('$StyleName','$Description','$image')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
?>
```

The image which I am selecting is above 500kb but the inserting image is getting broken and reducing its size into bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

instead of that use `file_get_contents` and add slashes.